# Declining a PhD offer after accepting?

Tags: phd, funding, rejection

I'm having a bit of a dilemma currently. Basically I applied (with my own research proposal) to three universities for a PhD. Whilst I was accepted at all three, I got no offer for funding from one, placed on the reserve list for funding for another, and offered funding for the third.

The university I was placed on the reserve list for was basically my dream university to go to for a PhD but after hearing nothing for 2 months I accepted the offer from the other university. I accepted about two weeks ago and have spoken to the people who will be my supervisors and they're both lovely people.

However, this evening I received an email from my preferred university offering me full funding. Obviously I would love to accept but I don't know how bad it looks to reject the other offer now? I would feel terrible, but one of my main concerns is also that people say the academic community is very tight-knit and obviously these academics all research a similar topic. I want to work in academia following my PhD and wouldn't want to start this career already having academics not a fan of me!

Any advice would be massively appreciated.